# wordpress plugin redirect from page to page permisson error

Tags: php, wordpress

im working on statestic wordpress plugin that allow the admin to get all the contributions of every contributor on the site daily, monthly .. etc, it have 3 pages, one contain a search button to search for username, the second page will contain the results of the name searched in first page, the 3rd page will contain a detailed report on every contribution durging a laps of time
i have create my plugin this way inside the plugin folder there is:
index.php

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: wathefty
* Plugin URI: aaaaa
* Description:aaaaaaa .
* Version: aaaaa
* Author: aaaaa
* Author URI: aaaaa
**/

function wathefty_admin_actions() {
    add_menu_page('wathefty stat Display', 'wathefty', 'manage_options', 'wathefty-stat-Display','wathefty_stat_Display');

}

function wathefty_stat_Display(){include('includes/wathefty-stat-Display.php');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'wathefty_admin_actions');



?>
```

style/style.css
includes/whatefty-stat-display.php

```
<form action="admin.php?page=stats" method="post" >
<fieldset class="fieldset">
<legend class="legend">Search</legend>
<label class="label">Search by author name:</label>
<input class="input" type="text" name="click" />
<button class="button1" name="Submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

includes/stats.php

```
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead">
<tr class="tr">
<td class="td" rowspan="2">Post author</td>
<td class="td" rowspan="2">Author category</td>
<td class="td" colspan="4">Number of posts</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr">
<td class="td">Daily</td>
<td class="td">Weekly</td>
<td class="td">Monthly</td>
<td class="td">Yearly</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tbody">
<tr class="tbody">
<td class="td">wathefty</td>
<td class="td">admin</td>
<td class="td"><a href="#">10</a></td>
<td class="td"><a href="#">42</a></td>
<td class="td"><a href="#">321</a></td>
<td class="td"><a href="#">1485</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

includes/contributions.php

for now i didnt create function to do the job, my only problem is that when i click on submit to be redirected to stats page i get this error

> wordpress You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have registered **stats** page in admin_pages.

### Solution

Adjust your code in *includes/whatefty-stat-display.php* to something like this:

```
<?php 
if( isset( $_POST['wathefty_submit'] ) ) {
  include( dirname(__FILE__) . '/stats.php' );
}
?>

<form method="post" >
<fieldset class="fieldset">
<legend class="legend">Search</legend>
<label class="label">Search by author name:</label>
<input class="input" type="text" name="click" />
<button class="button1" name="wathefty_submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

The main changes are in:

- removing **action** attribute from `<form>`
- including results (stats) page in same php file, in case there is **$_POST['wathefty_submit']** set

Note that `name` attribute of submit button was changed.

Optionally, you could enclose the form in **else** branch, so the form wouldn't be displayed on stats page.

### Alternative Solution

Alternative solution could be adding another menu page with **add_menu_page** function and including the second file there, but it doesn't seems to me right to have one menu page registered for form and other for results.

Answer (score 0):

look at the values in the ***wp_usermeta*** table as follows:

**wp_capabilities** should be a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}

**wp_user_level** should be **10**

it will fixed the problem if wont could you please give the link which you used to open your plugin panel >

Comment: where should i put that