# wordpress plugin devlopment issue "You do not have sufficient ..."

Tags: php, wordpress

im trying to make a plugin in wordpress, my plugin contain an index.php
and a folder containing 3 other php files

- pg1.php pg2.php pg3.php

the index contain this code

```
<?php

function myplu() {
    add_menu_page('my plugin Display', 'myplugin', 'manage_options', 'pg1','my_fun');

}

function my_fun(){include('includes/pg1.php');

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'myplu');

?>
```

pg1 contain a form that and when i click submit, data will be sent to pa2 and it should be the one diplayed but this dont happen and i get

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

note that my link before submit is 
http://localhost/wp_test/wp-admin/admin.php?page=pg1
and then after submit is like this
http://localhost/wp_test/wp-admin/admin.php?page=pg2

Comment: Post here code from pg1.php file. I suppose you have set wrong action in <form>, leading to another page (pg2.php), that is not registered as "menu_page"

Comment: yeah i beleive i did something wrong like that, but the question now is how to fix that

Comment: Try to register another menu page (pg2.php), or change action in form to send data to same page (pg1.php). Until you don't post here another codes, mainly pg1.php, I can't help you more.

Comment: i have already post this before with full code on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393530/wordpress-plugin-redirect-from-page-to-page-permisson-error/38394179#38394179

Comment: I've answered there. http://stackoverflow.com/q/38393530/6086593